# Setting an immutable field for later use

Tags: scala

I'm in a situation where I need to set a certain field in a singleton object so it can be used later.

```
def register(importantField: String): Unit = {
  Factory.setField(importantField)
}
```

where `Factory` is:

```
object Factory {
  var field: Option[String] = None

  def setField(importantField: String): Unit = {
    field = Option(importantField)
  }

  def functionThatWillBeCalledLater: Unit = {
    // do something with member "field"
  }
}
```

but I really want to avoid using `var`. Is there some kind of idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: It is not a good pratice to put state in `object`.  Singleton pattern might be [harmful](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3o4bk2/why_does_scala_support_singleton_when_its/) ... It is better to see `object` as module in Scala and not as the singleton Java version. I suggest you to rethink about the idea to have a global `object` as a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Global factories, besides being racy and breaking referential transparency, are also a nightmare for unit testing. You should really think about designing your code in a way, where you can keep all the "important fields" where you need them.

The trick is that instead of something like

```
    class Foo {
       def doFoo() = Factory.bar
    }
    Factory.register(param)
    new Foo().doFoo()
```

You would have to write

```
   class Foo { 
      def doFoo(factory: Factory) = factory.bar
   }
   new Foo().doFoo(new Factory(param)
```

Or maybe

```
   class Foo(factory: Factory) {
      def doFoo() = factory.bar
   }
   new Foo(new Factory(param)).doFoo
```

It may seem a bit tedious compared, to just throwing all the stuff into a global state object, and accessing it from everywhere ... but that's only as long as *all* of the uses of that function *everywhere* *always* use the same value of the parameter (in which case, it is better off just being a constant in the first place) *or* (perhaps, more importantly) until you start thinking about writing unit tests to test places that use your `Factory`. You cannot mock an object ... so, what will you do?

Answer (score 0):

Singleton objects have to be thread safe - since the object is static, there's no guarantee that only one thread will access it, so your call not to use a `var` is totally reasonable. All `val`s are final and guaranteed to be thread safe, but we can't say the same about `var`s (and, well, if we're talking about idiomatic, mutable state is generally frowned upon).

You could implement your own getter and setter (using proper synchronization) for a private var, or use a `scala.concurrent.Promise` for this purpose - a `Promise` can only be completed once, and is guaranteed to be thread safe.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Promise
object Factory {
  private val _field: Promise[String] = Promise()
  
  // the notation below allows you to set it via `Factory.field = "a"`
  def field_=(value: String): Boolean = _field.trySuccess(value)
  
  def field: Option[String] = _field.future.value.flatMap(_.toOption)
}
```

That said, the most idiomatic Scala way to approach factories with variable baseline conditions would be to create one with all the variables set to the values you need. An `object` is essentially just a `val`, so instead of an actual singleton object you could instantiate the `Factory` with all the parameters you need once they're available - and then just use that everywhere.